# Get AssignedTo.FirstName with REST not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, angularjs

How do I get the value of AssignedTo.FirstName with REST ( AJAX ) ?
I use Angular !

Other columns , it works as it should , but not AssignedTo column !

```
URL/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tet')/Items?$select=Title, AssignedTo/FirstName&$expand=AssignedTo
```

And

```
 URL/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Helpdesk')/Items?$select=Title, AssignedTo/FirstName&$expand=AssignedTo/Id
```

Givs

```
*{{Item.AssignedTo}}* = {"results":[{"__metadata":{"id":"4d16037f-fe8e-4f44-ac0b-","type":"SP.Data.UserInfoItem"},"FirstName":"Jack"}]}
```

Or

```
*{{Item.AssignedTo.FirstName}}* = Empty / NULL
```

Comment: https://umeaworks.wordpress.com/2015/04/01/sharepoint-rest-api-getting-user-information-from-list-item-field/   
"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Tasks')/items/?" +         "$select=ID,Title,Body,Issue/Id,TaskDueDate,Created,AssignedTo/FirstName,AssignedTo/LastName,AssignedTo/Name,AssignedTo/Id&" +
            "$expand=Issue/Id,AssignedTo/Id",

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the query is working as it should.  Your selector looks off. Try `Item.AssignedTo.results.FirstName`

Comment: thanks for the reply :) but unfortunately it did not work: /  

`Item.AssignedTo.results.FirstName`  = empty value
:(

Comment: What is the exact result received back from the call before you do anything?  Generally it should sit under `data.d.results[0].AssignedTo.results[0].FirstName`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this format.  Case is **very** important.  *Assuming SharePoint 2013*

```
"/Items?$expand=AssignedTo&$select=Title,Status,AssignedTo/EMail,AssignedTo/Title,AssignedTo/Id,AssignedTo/FirstName"
```

Comment: Can you walk through your answer? How does it solve the issue the OP had? How does it differ from what the OP did already?